# Memory consistency in OkHttp enqueue Callback methods? Do I need volatile?

Tags: multithreading, okhttp

When making an OkHttp call, do I need to worry about memory consistency in the callback methods?

Below is an example of what I'm asking. n is set to 5 on the main thread, and there are no other writes to n. It's then accessed in onResponse, which runs on another thread. Are we guaranteed n's value will be 5 when reading it on the other thread (and, if so, why)? Or do we need to make n volatile?

```
int n;
n = 5; // This is the only write to n. It happens on the main thread.
mOkHttpCall.enqueue(new Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(@Nonnull Call call, @Nonnull Response response) throws IOException 
    {
        // We're not on the main thread here. Is n guaranteed to be 5?
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

All interceptors and all callbacks will observe changes made before `call.enqueue()`. It’s the same guarantee (and the same mechanism!) as enqueueing work with an Executor.